# Como escribir un archivo de texto en nodejs con un texto ubicado en otro archivo

Tags: nodejs, fs

Necesito ayuda al escribir un archivo de texto. Ya busqué tutoriales y demás pero no sé como implementarlos con lo que me está pasando.

Resulta que estoy creando un editor de mapas (usando `ElectronJS`) para mi librería de desarrollo de juegos en `canvas`. Pero al momento de exportar el mapa a un archivo `.txt` o `.json` (he probado con fs de node), no sé como implementarlo, debido a que el texto que quiero escribir está en otro archivo `.js`.

Mi idea es: (resumida algo mas clara)

- Tengo un botón en un `index.html`.
- Y quiero que en el el evento `onclick` de ese botón llame a una función que escriba un archivo de texto.

Pero no sé dónde poner esa función: ¿en el `index.js` que inicializa npm o en el `game.js` que acompaña al `index.html` en una carpeta llamada `www`?.

Para que quede un poco mas claro (soy medio malo redactando preguntas se ve), voy a dejar  un pequeño esquema con los archivos y el código del `index.js` (que inicializa el `npm`) y el `index.html` (no se puede ejecutar ya que faltan algunos archivos como mi librería y el `game.js`).

[image: Pequeño esquema acerca de los archivos]

**index.js**

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require("electron")
const url = require("url")
const path = require("path")
const fs = require("fs")

app.on('ready', () => {
  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow ({ 
    width: 1000,
    height: 700
  });
  mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, "www/index.html"),
    protocol: "file",
    slashes: true
  }));
  mainWindow.setTop
});
```

**index.html**

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MDesigner 0.1 for Next-canvas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#19232d">
    <div style="float: right;">
      <br>
      <h3>Tilebox (max 64 tiles)</h3>
      <canvas style="background-color:black;" id="canvas" width=256 height=256>
      </canvas>
      <br>
      <br>
      <select multiple id="layers">
        <option value="layer1">Layer1</option>
        <option value="layer2">Layer2</option>
        <option value="layer3">Layer3</option>
      </select> 
      <br>
      <br>
      Name: &nbsp;
      <input type="text"> &nbsp;
      <input type="button" value="EXPORT">
    </div>
    <h1>Edit your own map!</h1>
    <canvas id ="viewport" style="float: left;background-color: black; border:2px solid black"></canvas>
    <script src="source.js"></script>
    <script src="next-canvas/next_canvas-audio.js"></script>
    <script src="next-canvas/next_canvas-random.js"></script>
    <script src="next-canvas/next_canvas-draw.js"></script>
    <script src="next-canvas/next_canvas-physics.js"></script>
    <script src="next-canvas/next_canvas.js"></script>
    <script src="game.js"></script>
    <script src="next-canvas/next_canvas-loop.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Perdón si no quedó claro, no he usado mucho StackOverflow y la verdad es que estoy medio confundido.